# How to change execution order of express Middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, middleware

I have created 2 api's- /api1, /api2 and 4 middlewares - validate1, validate 2, validationResult, checkAdmin. My routes become so long and i want to keep them clean.

```
router.post('/api1', validate1, validationResult, checkAdmin, user.updateUserData);

router.post('/api2', validate2, validationResult, checkAdmin, user.CreateUser);
```

So, I tried router.all() method and put all common middleware in this method. But the middleware are not running in order that i want.

router.all("*", validationResult, checkAdmin)

```
//common middleware
router.all("*", validationResult, checkAdmin);

//routes
router.post('/api1', validate1, user.updateUserData);

router.post('/api2', validate2, user.updateUserData);
```

I there any way to order these middleware. Order -

Validate Middleware --> validationResult --> checkAdmin

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to short the syntax:

```
const adminChain = (validateX, userValidate) => [validateX, validationResult, checkAdmin, userValidate];

router.post('/api1', ...adminChain(validate1, user.updateUserData));
router.post('/api2', ...adminChain(validate2,  user.CreateUser));
```

More info about the spread operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: It showing me an error. Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: @AshutoshSharma, whats the output of console.log(...adminChain(validate1, user.updateUserData)) ?

Comment: This error occur while saving the route file, Nodemon server crashed.

Comment: Right, just do the console.log. You must have an undefined or wrong middleware function. Double check the var names!

Comment: Yeah, Since I'm using express-validator. My first middleware look like - exports.registerValidate = checkSchema({  ........ ..... ..... })